# iptables not blocking access via ports?

Tags: iptables, port, ipset

I'm running `Debian 8.11` with `iptables v1.4.21` and `ipset v6.23, protocol version: 6`.

I'm trying to block access to certain ports for all but a small set of hosts, but it doesn't seem to be working.

First of all, I put a small list of IP addresses into an `ipset` list called `allowed-hosts`. Then, after running `sudo /sbin/iptables -F` and `sudo /sbin/iptables -X`, I issue the following commands:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-port 110,143,993,995 -j DROP
sudo /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --destination-port 110,143,993,995 -m set --match-set allowed-hosts src -j ACCEPT
```

However, even after doing this, clients from IP addresses that are not present `allowed-hosts` are still successfully connecting to all of the named ports.

There are no other `iptables` rules in effect.

Here are the results of `sudo /sbin/iptables -L` ...

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports pop3,imap2,imaps,pop3s match-set allowed-hosts src
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports pop3,imap2,imaps,pop3s

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And here are the results of `sudo /sbin/iptables-save` ...

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Jun  8 11:53:09 2022
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [16777464:2727427757]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [18889599:33356814491]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun  8 11:53:09 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Jun  8 11:53:09 2022
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [21444955:3000669583]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [18889599:33356814491]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun  8 11:53:09 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Jun  8 11:53:09 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun  8 11:53:09 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Jun  8 11:53:09 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [21444955:3000669583]
:INPUT ACCEPT [21444952:3000669415]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [18889599:33356814491]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [18889599:33356814491]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun  8 11:53:09 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Wed Jun  8 11:53:09 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2130649:527089827]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4465281:1887206637]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 110,143,993,995 -m set --match-set allowed-hosts src -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 110,143,993,995 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun  8 11:53:09 2022
```

What might I be doing incorrectly?

Thank you in advance.

****UPDATE****

First of all, "src" indeed is being specified, contrary to what was suggested in the comment below. It appears in the "... src -j ACCEPT" line, above.

Secondly, the syntax of these `iptables` commands that I am using comes from what is shown both in the `iptables` docs and in discussions that were found via web searches.

Thirdly, look above at the `iptables -L` output. This clearly shows that connections to the ports should be accepted from `source=anywhere` to `destination=anywhere` for the IP addresses in the `allowed-hosts` list. This also clearly shows that connections to the ports should be dropped from `source=anywhere` to `destination=anywhere` for the IP addresses that are **not** in the `allowed-hosts` list.

At least that's what `iptables` seems to be telling me. However, connections to these ports from IP addresses that are not in the `allowed-hosts` list are still being accepted on my machine.

Also, if I do `ipset test allowed-hosts aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd`, where "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd" represents an IP address which is **not** in `allowed-hosts`, I properly get this following output:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd is NOT in set allowed-hosts.
```

And if I do `ipset test allowed-hosts www.xxx.yyy.zzz`, where "www.xxx.yyy.zzz" represents an IP address which **is** in `allowed-hosts`, I properly get this following output:

```
www.xxx.yyy.zzz is in set allowed-hosts.
```

Looking at the output from `iptables-save`, above, what else in my configuration could be causing these connections to ports not in `allowed-hosts` to be accepted?

Thank you again, in advance.

Comment: Oh ... thank you. How should I define `src` ?

Comment: I need allowed hosts because that is a very small set. I want to reject *most* accesses to those ports and only allow a few IP addresses to succeed. So, I want to do a match on "allowed-hosts" to let the "good" hosts connect, and I want to drop everyone else in the world who tries to access through any of those ports.
I'll try to figure out how to set "src". Thank you

Comment: PS: "src" appears in the "... -j ACCEPT" command that I listed above. Did you miss it? Or are you saying that "src" needs to be defined somewhere else, as well?

Comment: works for me with a similar ruleset and an ipset created with `ipset create foo hash:ip` . You have `policy ACCEPT` shown there in the iptables output, so make sure you're not accidentally testing with a part outside of that list... Also, you could try to sanitycheck with rules for single ports, and check the rule counters when testing to see if the right ones get triggered.

Comment: Thank you very much, @ilkkachu, for reading and understanding my question and for your helpful suggestion. It turns out that I am not accidentally testing with anything outside of my list. Rather, it turns out that my iptables rules are working, after all, and I was in error to think that they were failing. My Answer here explains how I made that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is working, after all. I am very, very sorry for the false alarm.

I incorrectly thought that it wasn't working properly for the following reason ...

I am using both `postfix` and `dovecot`, and I have set up `postfix` to use `dovecot` to perform its authentication services.

I have set up `dovecot` to write its debug and logging messages to a file called `/var/log/mailclient.log`, while `postfix` is configured to log via `syslog`.

I wasn't thinking clearly, and forgot about the fact that `postfix`'s authentication attempts would also cause entries to appear in this same `dovecot` log file, given that `dovecot` is the one that is performing this `postfix` authentication.

I am only using my `iptables` rules to block `pop3` and `imap` (ports 110, 143, 993, and 995), and I am not blocking `postfix`'s ports.

Given this way in which I set up `postfix` authentication, there are entries in that `/var/log/mailclient.log` file for all of the `postfix` login attempts, as well as for the `dovecot` login attempts. I was not paying attention well when reading those entries in this log file, and I mistakenly thought that they were login attempts for `pop3` and `imap`, instead of `smtp` login attempts. Therefore, I mistook these `smtp` login attempts (which I am not blocking) for `pop3` and `imap` login attempts.

Once I understood my error, I more carefully examined and analyzed my `dovecot` log file, and I now realize that indeed, none of the `pop3` nor `imap` connections are coming to dovecot, except for those which originate from the small subset of hosts which I have put into my "allowed-hosts" `ipset` list.

Therefore, the `iptables` entries that I have listed above **are** indeed working properly, after all.

Once again, I apologize for my false alarm, and I'm just glad that this is working.

Perhaps this question and discussion could help someone else in the future who might make the same mistake as I made.